# Remove WooCommerce Product Addons addons.min.js script from output

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

The function code below outputs a referral to a javascript file called `addons.min.js` I believe this is done in line 6 of the code.

Because I don't want to edit the plugins core `addons.min.js` file I have created `my-custom-addons.min.js` file and added it to the wp-footer (via wp_enqueue_script).

All good but I can't remove the original referral.

I tried to use

```
// Remove plugins core addons.min.js
function iw_wcpa_script_remove() {
    if ( is_product() ) {
        wp_dequeue_script( 'woocommerce-addons' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'woocommerce-addons' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wc_quick_view_enqueue_scripts', 'iw_wcpa_script_remove', 99 );


// Add custom addons.min.js
function iw_wcpa_script_add() {
    if ( is_product() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'iw-woocommerce-addons', get_site_url() . '/wp-content/uploads/iwebbers/js/addons.min.js' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'iw_wcpa_script_add' );
```

But `addons.min.js` still keeps coming up in my HTML output like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://iwebbers.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-product-addons/assets/js/addons.min.js'></script>
```

I'm completely in the dark here how to get this done.

Anyone?

If it helps, here's the live page to see the whole HTML source:
https://iwebbers.com/samenstellen/gratis-website-pakket

And just to be clear, I can't edit the function below because it's plugins core.

```
public function addon_scripts() {
    $suffix = defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ? '' : '.min';

    wp_register_script( 'accounting', WC()->plugin_url() . '/assets/js/accounting/accounting' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery' ), '0.4.2' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'woocommerce-addons', plugins_url( basename( dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) ) ) . '/assets/js/addons' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery', 'accounting' ), '1.0', true );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to hook *wp_enqueue_scripts* instead of wp *wp_footer* with the high priority value:

```
add_action( 'wc_quick_view_enqueue_scripts', 'iw_wcpa_custom_script', 99 );
```

**UPDATE**

replace `wocoomerce-addons` with `woocommerce-addons` in your `iw_wcpa_script_remove`

Comment: Didn't work :( I've placed my code above in your answer.

Comment: Check what hook is used for addon_scripts function?

Comment: add_action( 'wc_quick_view_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'addon_scripts' ) ); 
This is what you mean by filter?

Comment: As much as I would have liked to give you the credits.... It still doesn't work. The script is still called in the html source. I've updated my question so you can see the total snippets I use.

Comment: I found mistake in your `iw_wcpa_script_remove` function: replace `wocoomerce-addons` with `woocommerce-addons`

Comment: I'm so stupid but I couldn't believe it would be that easy and I was right. Maybe with copy/paste I gave the wrong code. I've edited my question but still the script comes up in HTML. It's like the devil...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function remove_product_addons_js() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'woocommerce-addons' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'remove_product_addons_js', 0 );
```